# How do I enable asynchronous behavior using async /await while writing API methods in Web API

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core-webapi

I have written below ASP.NET API code to return employee data

```
public async Task<IActionResult> employeegroups()
{
    try
    {
        var employeegroups = _context.EmployeeGroups.Select(p => new EmployeeGroupsEntity()
        {
            id = p.Key,
            name = p.Name
        }).ToList();

        return Ok(employeegroups);
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

I get this warning:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread

So, I tried to add `await':

```
var employeegroups = await _context.EmployeeGroups.Select(p => new EmployeeGroupsEntity()
{
    id = p.Key,
    name = p.Name
}).ToList();
```

But I get this warning:

> List 'EmployeeGroupsEntity' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of​ type List 'EmployeeGroupsEntity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Here is my model:

```
public class EmployeeGroupsEntity
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *Where* did you try adding the `await` keyword?

Comment: just like this      await _context.EmployeeGroups.Select(   updated the question

Comment: Is that an entity framework context? Use ToListAsync() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are working with `Task<T>` as return type of method in combination with  `async` keyword we should also be using `await` keyword that will make sure that the calling thread is not blocked and will resume the method lines execution followed after the `await`. So you should be calling the `ToListAsync` method with `await` like:

```
var employeegroups = await _context.EmployeeGroups.Select(p => new EmployeeGroupsEntity()
        {
            id = p.Key,
            name = p.Name
        }).ToListAsync();
```